# dbmail is stopping sometimes in sql

Tags: c#, sql, dbmail

sometimes dbmail in sql stops sending emails with this error:
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2018-05-07T08:54:34). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (A recipient must be specified.).
)
and sometimes it does send.
the above happens for all mail profiles, i tried everything, still the same.
now i enabled one of the profile in sql server agent, it's working perfectly but the others are sometimes working and sometimes don't.
please help!

Comment: Without code it's hardly possible to help you. Is it possible that your DB is missing values? `recipient must be specified` seems a pretty straight forward error. Also this does not seem to be related to C#.

Comment: even if i send a test mail, sometimes it does send and sometimes it doesn't, i check all the recipients before sending any email and i just checked one mailitem, nothing is wrong with the recipients.

Answer (score 0):

Verify recipient email id, it might be null or empty.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: there is no email that is empty or null